# IE7+ 'Shrink to Fit' making text too small

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, printing

Have a page that displays `<p>`s in 12pt font. It prints fine in any browser except for IE7+. In IE7+ Shrink to Fit is selected by default in the user's browser and therefore it prints the text closer to 9pt.

We need to have this text printed at 12pt. Is there any CSS or JS solution to force IE to print a specific font size?

Our only thought is to convert the page to a PDF and then have the user print the PDF.

Saw some people online recommend this command but it's not working for us.

```
document.execCommand('print', false, null);
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: The text on the printed page is still "Shrunk to fit" and is about 9pt instead of 12pt.

Comment: Trying to get the text, just plain text in <p> tags to print at 12pt when printed from IE7+. If you change from "Shrink to Fit" to "100%" in IE Print Preview window it prints fine but need to have it printed at 12pt by default

Comment: I've never heard of a css term "Shrink to fit". Why are you using pt's instead of em's or px's?

Comment: "Shrink to Fit" has nothing to do with css. It seems to be IE's "Shrink to Fit" that is the issue. With "Shrink to Fit" selected in IE text prints at 9pt. If you change that to 100% it prints at 12pt.

Comment: have body, div and table width's all set to 720px and font size set to 12pt. If you think setting these to something else would work to get this page to print 12pt in IE let me know

Answer (score 3):

OK..fixed my issue. I had a header div that was 850px wide and the body content was 720px. The header div didn't need to be 850px for printing because the bgimage was not printed in the print css.

So IE's "Shrink to Fit" was shrinking the page to the printable width (about 720px) and because the header was 850px the content div was scaled down along with the header. It made everything about  15% smaller to fit the 850px header in the printable page.

So just updated the header width to 720px and it prints the proper size now.

Comment: Thanks for this. It helped me find my IE printing problem. A div in the header had a large absolute width. Once I changed it to a relative width in the print style sheet, the "shrink to fit" thing was no longer being triggered :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional commenting for IE, this way you can specify separately what font you want to use for it

```
<!--[if IE 7]>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7style.css">
<![endif]-->
```

There's a wide range of different ones you can use. This site lists them all

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Conditional comments don't work in IE10, while shrink to fit is still enabled by default in IE10.